# neo4j browser not running queries spinning wheel

Tags: neo4j

I'm a newbie with Neo4j and I am attempting to set up a local Neo4j Causal Cluster where all nodes are on the same machine (CENTOS6.6 x64). I can login to each node through Firefox browser using localhost:7474, localhost:7475, localhost:7476.  However, when I try to create a node/database it just shows spinning wheel and never stops.

I tried using :sysinfo and it shows all nodes with correct leader and followers and port numbers.

I can use the cypher-shell and it allows me to create nodes and run match queries etc.

I've disabled firewall and stopped iptables and diabled proxy settings but it still won't let me create a node through the browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just type "**error**" (or anything) on the browser and execute it, does it throw an error or keep spinning wheel?

Comment: Have you enabled the `Use bolt+routing` functionnality in the browser ?